# c# windows 10 permanent notification

Tags: c#, windows-10

is it possible to create a permanent notification at the notification bar in Windows 10?
Also it is necessary to do this in a windows form application and not an universal windows app.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

To do it in a WinForms app you'll need to use the [desktop bridge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop) to create the notifications.

It's not possible to have a toast that can't be dismissed from the action centre (which is what I assume you mean by "notifications area") but you can detect when it's removed and then add another back in. There are already a number of apps which do this as a way of having "permanent notifications".

Comment: Thank you I will try it tomorrow.